# How to change background of textblock in an event in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, background, border, textblock

Unlike WPF, TextBlock has no background property.
I've seen that a workaround for that would be wrapping the textblock in a border and changing the border's background.

Now I want to change the border's background in an event triggered when the textblock is loaded.

checking the Parent property of the triggered textblock I see it only has a reference to the stackpanel but not the border. How can I change the borders background in the event function?

the not working code i've tried is this:

```
    private void BitText_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock bitText = sender as TextBlock;
        Border border = bitText.Parent as Border;
        if ((int)bitText.DataContext == 1)
        {
            bitText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGreen);
            border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkGreen);
        }
        else
        {
            bitText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Gray);
            border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        }
    }
```

The XAML Code:

```
                                         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Border Background="Gray">
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name="BitText" Text="{Binding}" Loaded="BitText_Loaded"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Did you try to first cast `bitText.Parent` to a `StackPanel` and then cast the `Parent` of the `StackPanel` to a `Border`?

Comment: Yes thank you that worked, my bad for not noticing that I've wrapped the border around the stackpanel too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `bitText.Parent` to a `StackPanel` and then cast the `Parent` of the `StackPanel` to a `Border`:

```
private void BitText_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock bitText = sender as TextBlock;
    StackPanel stackPanel = bitText.Parent as StackPanel;
    Border border = stackPanel.Parent as Border;
    //...
}
```